# ¿Por qué no puedo ver los archivos que subo por PHP en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, template

No puedo ver los archivos que subo por formulario.

Creé un template con un formulario y los archivos sí se guardan en la carpeta del servidor, pero no logro hacer que se muestren en la galería de medios de wordpress.

Tengo entendido que wordpress trabaja mucho con la base de datos, ¿hay algún hook que tenga que ejecutar o tendría que conectarme a la base de datos de otra forma?

Lo que hice en mi template fue lo siguiente:

```html
<?php

/**
 * Valida que el nombre del archivo no esté vacio
 * @return boolean
 */
function validateForm(string $fileName, string $tempFileName): bool
{
    if ($fileName == '' || $tempFileName == '') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Sube un archivo a la carpeta "wp-content/uploads/archivos/"
 * @return boolean
 */
function subirArchivo(string $tempFileName, string $fileName): bool
{
    // ¿La carpeta "archivos" NO existe?
    if (!file_exists('wp-content/uploads/archivos')) {

        // Crea la carpeta
        mkdir('wp-content/uploads/archivos', 0777, true);
    }

    // Intenta subir el archivo
    if (move_uploaded_file($tempFileName, 'wp-content/uploads/archivos/' . $fileName)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Inicia el proceso
$datosEnviados  = false; // ¿Se envió formulario? Aún no
$fileSaved      = false; // ¿Se guardó el archivo? Aún no

$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'] ?? '';
$archivo_temp   = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'] ?? '';

// ¿Sí se envió el formulario?
if ($_FILES) {
    $datosEnviados = true; // Ahora sí
}

// ¿Los datos del formulario son correctos?
if (validateForm($nombre_archivo, $archivo_temp)) {

    // Sube el archivo y retorna VERDADERO (true)
    $fileSaved = subirArchivo($archivo_temp, $nombre_archivo);
}
?>

<?php get_header() ?>

<main id="main">
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php if ($datosEnviados && $fileSaved): ?>
            <div style="color: #299A0B; border: solid 1px; padding: 5px; background: #B1E2A1" role="alert">
                Archivo guardado correctamente. <a style="color: #299A0B; font-size: 1.2rem; padding: 5px 8px;" href="pagina-ejemplo/">&times;</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($datosEnviados && !$fileSaved): ?>
            <div style="color: #8f0222; border: solid 1px; padding: 5px; background: #EFA992;" role="alert">
                El archivo NO se pudo guardar, puede ser que no hayas elegido un archivo. <a style="color: #8f0222; font-size: 1.2rem; padding: 5px 8px;" href="pagina-ejemplo/">&times;</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <h1>Sube tu archivo</h1>

        <!-- Formulario Archivos -->
        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <input style="width: 100%; padding: 4px;" type="file" name="archivo" required>
            </fieldset>

            <button style="padding: 8px; color: white; cursor: pointer; background: blue; border: none;">Subir Archivo</button>
        </form>
        
        <small>Nota: Tus archivos se guardan en la carpeta "/wp-content/uploads/archivos/TU-ARCHIVO".</small>
    </div>
</main>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

He buscado por Internet pero solo me recomiendan plugins pero lo quiero hacer sin plugins porque no creo que sea mucho código lo que me falta.

Comment: Wordpress no solo sube archivos a la galería, también los registra en la base de datos y ese es el paso que te falta para que aparezcan. Se deben insertar en la tabla `wp_posts` con `post_type = "attachment"`, entre algunas otras cosas. Probablemente no es mucho código lo que te falta, pero sí algo de investigación para lograr tu objetivo.

Comment: Gracias, en efecto. Me falta registrar el archivo en la DB.